# mix background position in pixels and percentage

Tags: css

I try this, and is not woking:

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/bgr.jpg);
    background-position: 156px, right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

is there a way to make this working?

Comment: Remove the comma. `background-position: 156px right;`. And I don't see a percentage anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove comma.

```
body {
    background-image: url(images/bgr.jpg);
    background-position: 156px right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need not comma here:

```
background-position: 156px, right;
```

right is:

```
background-position: 156px right;
```